# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys' for IE

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-9

I found strange for the following code:

```
var allextRules = Ext.util.CSS.getRules();

Object.keys(allextRules).forEach(function(key) {
    var keyname = key;
    if(keyname.indexOf("js") != -1){
        Ext.util.CSS.removeStyleSheet(keyname);
        console.log(keyname + " Removed");
    }
});
```

When the above work is tested in other browser (say - Google Chrome), there is no error. However, when tested in IE 9, there is error as follows:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
```

According to this article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), the `Object.keys` is supported by IE.

Have I miss out something?

Comment: have you got ie9 in ie9 broswer mode in developer tool bar?

Comment: Also, have you tried defining the function via the code in the "Compatibility" section of the link you gave? Even if IE9 does actually support the keys method, defining it yourself won't hurt. And if it still doesn't work, then you have a better understanding of your problem

Answer (score 10):

Try add this code before your

```
    if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null) throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');

      var result = [];

      for (var prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) result.push(prop);
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (var i=0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) result.push(dontEnums[i]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
  })()
};
```

here is more details about this issue - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: I just added the above code to the top of my script that needed the hasOwnProperty method and IE 8 instantly started working again. Thank you!!!

Comment: I know why this doesn't work in IE for some people: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys Array.prototype.keys() doesn't work for IE (up to 11) so this is why it might not be working for some.

Answer (score 3):

in method 'forEach' (error script438: object doesn't support this property or method 'foreEach', in IE 9), 
the soluction was:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

Font: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_foreach.htm