# How to get parameter like (parameter name contains) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

i am using the following method to get parameter by name:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and i was wondering how to change it to get parameter that contains some string for example, i want to get the parameter that contains the word "document" but the whole parameter name is not "document".

please advise, thanks.

Comment: `window.location.search.indexOf('document') != -1`

Comment: @adeneo this checks if it exists but doesn't return the value of the param, how to get the param value then ?

Comment: If you're allowed to use jQuery, it would be realy easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
 val = location.search.match(/document.*?=([^&]*)/)[1]
```

Although I'd rather use a function that converts the whole query string into an object (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/989121)) and simply apply a filter afterwards:

```
params = urlParams()
ks = Object.keys(params).filter(function(k) { return k.indexOf("document") >= 0 })
if(ks)
   value = params[ks[0]];
```

This way you can easily support multiple params (as in `document1=foo&document2=bar`) and avoid ugly dynamic regexp construction.

In older browsers you can use this instead of Object.keys/filter:

```
ks = []
for(var k in params)
     if(k.indexOf("document") >= 0)
        ks.push(k);
```

Comment: i have var called urlParams that contains array of params as in the link you posted and when i tried the following code: 
`ks = Object.keys(urlParams).filter(function(k) { return k.indexOf("DocumentType") >= 0 })` i got the error
` Object doesn't support property or method 'keys' `

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh: `Object.keys` is IE9+, for older IE's use `for..in` or a shim.

Comment: found solution for my issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306294/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-keys-for-ie

Comment: filter also is not supported in IE<9, can you please edit the answer to mention that it works for IE >=9 and if possible add solution for older version.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
function getParameterByPartialName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&][^&#]*" + name + "[^=]*=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

This however, will return only the 1st match, there might be more parameters that have a similar name. You could return an array of key-value pairs for all matches.

Comment: how to change it to return an array ?